# Eclipse corrupt apk

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Whenever I generate an apk or run an application with eclipse. The app runs as expected until you leave the app or crashes. After that it will only display a white background.

The only way to make it run again is to clear cache/uninstall application and run the code again.

So I brought down the issue to my eclipse. It works perfectly on other computers. I am not sure what to do next

Should I just reinstall eclipse?

Comment: are u running the app on phone. If yes , then please paste the logcat ...

Comment: nothing appears on the logcat, as i said the app runs perfectly on a different eclipse.

Comment: if it helps, when I run the debugger it stops at getApplications calls, Handler and Thread runnable